# How to send and receive data with Com ports in android and linux based board?

Tags: android, linux

I have emb 4500 board which have 5 Com ports. i want to send and receive data with this com ports but i don't know how to do this.

Serial port operation node: /dev/ttymxc0~/dev/ttymxc4.

Please,help me!